# firebase cloud functions http request to external api

Tags: firebase, api, google-cloud-functions

I want to build a cloud function that returns a result from an API request.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

exports.getData = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
 const result = await fetch("3RD PARTY API URL")
 response.send(result);
});
```

and for some reason i get an

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

what could cause that?
my opinion is that it has something to do with not sending a request correctly or not handling asynchronous code properly

Comment: Check the functions log in the console.

Comment: yep. you got it. "Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions" thanks!